# Resizing and positioning panels in another panel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, panel

I'm giving my panels inside another panel (this panel is in a usercontrol) a fixed location and a maximum size that changes with the size of the panel there in. Neither the resize or location works  properly. The resize does happen but its to quickly. The location is fine if you only have 1 pinpanel for output and input. When you have more then 1 the locations are fixed but you need to resize the panel to resize to see the other panels. Could you point me in the right direction if you see the problem?

I have a panel drawPanel in this case that i use as a sort of background for the usercontrol. Inside this drawPanel i'm placing pinpanels. I want these pinpanels to resize with the usercontrol and give them a fixed location

```
    private void OnClickPinPanel(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (source is PinPanel p)
        {
            int index;
            if ((index = Array.IndexOf(inputPins, p)) >= 0)
            {
                ClickedPinPanel?.Invoke(index, true);
            }
            else
            {
                ClickedPinPanel?.Invoke(Array.IndexOf(outputPins, p), false);
            }
        }
        //else log here
    }

    private void CreatePinPanels(bool isInput)
    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = -(int)(this.Width * 0.05)/2;

        if (isInput)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < inputPins.Length; i++)
            {
                y += (i + 1) * (this.Height / inputPins.Length + 1);
                inputPins[i] = new PinPanel()
                {
                    Location = new Point(x, y),
                    Size = new Size((int)(this.Width * 0.05), (int)(this.Width * 0.05)),
                    Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right,
                };
                inputPins[i].Click += OnClickPinPanel;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            x += this.Width - (int)(this.Width * 0.1);
            for (int i = 0; i < outputPins.Length; i++)
            {
                y += (i + 1) * (this.Height / inputPins.Length+1);
                outputPins[i] = new PinPanel()
                {
                    Size = new Size((int)(this.Width * 0.1), (int)(this.Width * 0.1)),
                    Location = new Point(x, y),
                    Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right
                };
                outputPins[i].Click += OnClickPinPanel;
            }
        }
    }
```

The result i get now is that the pinpanels get a fixed location but when you have more then 1 pinpanel, the location is wrong its like if he thinks that the usercontrol is bigger then it is [Reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYWHh.png). In order to see all the pins i have to resize and get this [After resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDgKa.png)

I want it to look like this 
[expectations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTGI0.png)

Comment: Your code need to move the left and top properties.  When one control get larger the surrounding controls need to move so they do not overlap  onto the one that grows larger so you need to change the left and top properties.

Comment: @jdweng What about the positioning of the pinpanels? It needs to be of a certain size to see them all and there in the wrong location

Comment: I specifically use the word "Controls" not panel because I was referring to ALL objects on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this out.

Here is my test rig:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        numericUpDown1.Value = someChip1.NumberInputPins;
        numericUpDown2.Value = someChip1.NumberOutputPins;
    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        someChip1.NumberInputPins = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
    }

    private void numericUpDown2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        someChip1.NumberOutputPins = (int)numericUpDown2.Value;
    }

}
```

Sample chip with 5 inputs and 3 outputs:

[image]

Here is my PinPanel UserControl (just draws an ellipse/pin the size of the control):

```
public partial class PinPanel : UserControl
{

    public PinPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void PinPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(this.ClientRectangle.Width - 1, this.ClientRectangle.Height - 1));
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, rc);
    }

    private void PinPanel_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Refresh();
    }

}
```

And finally, my SomeChip UserControl:

```
public partial class SomeChip : UserControl
{

    public event PinPanelClick ClickedPinPanel;
    public delegate void PinPanelClick(int index, bool input);

    private PinPanel[] inputPins;
    private PinPanel[] outputPins;

    private int _NumberInputPins = 2;
    public int NumberInputPins
    {
        get {
            return _NumberInputPins;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0 && value != _NumberInputPins)
            {
                _NumberInputPins = value;
                CreatePinPanels();
                this.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }

    private int _NumberOutputPins = 1;
    public int NumberOutputPins
    {
        get
        {
            return _NumberOutputPins;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0 && value != _NumberOutputPins)
            {
                _NumberOutputPins = value;
                CreatePinPanels();
                this.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }

    public SomeChip()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SomeChip_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreatePinPanels();
        RepositionPins();
    }

    private void SomeChip_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Refresh();
    }

    private void SomeChip_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int PinHeight;
        // draw the input pin runs
        if (inputPins != null)
        {
            PinHeight = (int)((double)this.Height / (double)_NumberInputPins);
            for (int i = 0; i < NumberInputPins; i++)
            {
                int Y = (i * PinHeight) + (PinHeight / 2);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, Y, this.Width / 4, Y);
            }
        }
        // draw the output pin runs
        if (outputPins != null)
        {
            PinHeight = (int)((double)this.Height / (double)_NumberOutputPins);
            for (int i = 0; i < NumberOutputPins; i++)
            {
                int Y = (i * PinHeight) + (PinHeight / 2);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, this.Width - this.Width / 4, Y, this.Width, Y);
            }
        }
        //draw the chip itself (takes up 50% of the width of the UserControl)
        Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(new Point(this.Width / 4, 0), new Size(this.Width / 2, this.Height - 1));
        using (SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(sb, rc);
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc);
        RepositionPins();
    }

    private void CreatePinPanels()
    {
        if (inputPins != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < inputPins.Length; i++)
            {
                if (inputPins[i] != null && !inputPins[i].IsDisposed)
                {
                    inputPins[i].Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        inputPins = new PinPanel[_NumberInputPins];
        for (int i = 0; i < inputPins.Length; i++)
        {
            inputPins[i] = new PinPanel();
            inputPins[i].Click += OnClickPinPanel;
            this.Controls.Add(inputPins[i]);
        }
        if (outputPins != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < outputPins.Length; i++)
            {
                if (outputPins[i] != null && !outputPins[i].IsDisposed)
                {
                    outputPins[i].Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        outputPins = new PinPanel[_NumberOutputPins];
        for (int i = 0; i < outputPins.Length; i++)
        {
            outputPins[i] = new PinPanel();
            outputPins[i].Click += OnClickPinPanel;
            this.Controls.Add(outputPins[i]);
        }
    }

    private void OnClickPinPanel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PinPanel p = (PinPanel)sender;
        if (inputPins.Contains(p))
        {
            ClickedPinPanel?.Invoke(Array.IndexOf(inputPins, p), true);
        }
        else if (outputPins.Contains(p))
        {
            ClickedPinPanel?.Invoke(Array.IndexOf(inputPins, p), false);
        }
    }

    private void RepositionPins()
    {
        int PinRowHeight, PinHeight;
        if (inputPins != null)
        {
            PinRowHeight = (int)((double)this.Height / (double)_NumberInputPins);
            PinHeight = (int)Math.Min((double)(PinRowHeight / 2), (double)this.Height * 0.05);
            for (int i = 0; i < inputPins.Length; i++)
            {
                if (inputPins[i] != null && !inputPins[i].IsDisposed)
                {
                    inputPins[i].SetBounds(0, (int)((i * PinRowHeight) + (PinRowHeight /2 ) - (PinHeight / 2)), PinHeight, PinHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        if (outputPins != null)
        {
            PinRowHeight = (int)((double)this.Height / (double)_NumberOutputPins);
            PinHeight = (int)Math.Min((double)(PinRowHeight / 2), (double)this.Height * 0.05);
            for (int i = 0; i < outputPins.Length; i++)
            {
                if (outputPins[i] != null && !outputPins[i].IsDisposed)
                {
                    outputPins[i].SetBounds(this.Width - PinHeight, (int)((i * PinRowHeight) + (PinRowHeight / 2) - (PinHeight / 2)), PinHeight, PinHeight);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```